# trouble using boolean comparison for if-loop in bash --> believe it has to do with data type

Tags: bash, shell

I have been having this problem that is driving me nuts. Basically I am using an if statement that runs when a piece of data from the first line in a .dat file created using a python script is compared to 1. So I have it set up like this:

```
t=$(<data.dat)
if [ "$t" -eq "1" ]
then
    do something
else
    do something else
fi
```

but it never works! Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I am using shell. Also, this for loop is within a while loop, so maybe I am missing something to do with nesting?

Comment: Eep! I actually meant `if [ "$t" -eq "1" ]` and typed it incorrectly in my original post. So the issue I am having is with `"$t"`

Comment: If you `echo $t` after reading it in, does it contain what you expect?

Comment: Yeah, for some reason it is still not working. Is there something I need to be particularly mindful of since the if statement is nested within a while loop?

Comment: perhaps the problem is in the part of the code not posted?

Comment: There's nothing about while loops in general that would impact this example.  You would need to update the question with a reproducible failure (e.g., a complete script example and the data) to figure out what's going on, because the code you have posted here works just fine. Also consider running your script with `sh -x` to get a verbose trace of the execution.

Comment: Maybe a special char int the `data.dat` output that fail the integer comparison. What's the output of `echo "$t" | cat -A` ?

Comment: Do you have more than one line in the file?  The way you are reading the file will create a single multi-line string in `t`.

Comment: Replace `t=$(<data.dat)` by `t=$(tr -cd '0-9' <data.dat)` to remove unwanted characters from data.dat.

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` generate a good input data file, verify it:

```
echo 1 > data2.dat
hexdump -C data2.dat
```

...which outputs:

```
00000000  31 0a                                             |1.|
00000002
```

Now run `hexdump -C data.dat` on that *python* data output.  It will either be the same as the output shown above (i.e. '*31 0a*'), or different.
If it's the same, then the problem must be a typo or other error in the unspecified *do something* then *do something else* `bash` code.  If the `hexdump` output is not the same, the problem is in the *python* code.

Proof that the above output file *data2.dat* is good, and needs no further filtering follows.

This `bash` code is correct:

```
if [ "$(<data2.dat)" = "1" ]
then
  echo yes
else
  echo no
fi
```

Output:

```
yes
```

Retesting with a '*2*' instead of a '*1*' (one-liner, same as above, but no `hexdump`):

```
echo 2 > data2.dat; if [ "$(<data2.dat)" -eq "1" ]; then  echo yes; else echo no; fi
```

Output:

```
no
```